# Illustrator CC artifacts in text stroke

Tags: adobe-illustrator, stroke, error, bug

I'm working on a logo in Illustrator CC, and have a single letter (text) with 5 strokes, but for some reason there are random black artifacts/lines that appear in the stroke. I hoped it was just a preview issue, as the artifacts jump around as I zoom in and out. I exported a jpeg and the artifacts are in the exported image. Does anyone have a clue as to why this is happening?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to turn opengl acceleration off.

Comment: Actually, since you said that, I noticed GPU acceleration wasn't available. I entered BIOS and enabled Nvidia (Thinkpad), then the GPU acceleration option was available in Illustrator settings. I checked the box to enable it, and it FIXED the problem. The lines are gone! Hours of headache for 1 little checkbox. Thank you!

Comment: If you solved your problem by yourself or with the suggestion from a comment, please consider answering your own question and ticking that answer as the accepted one. That will tell other visitors with the same issues that this was the right solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you say "text" you mean real text ? Or vectorize text ?

Anyway in some cases, font aren't perfect so you need to tweak them a bit. I think there's small gap in this font so I suggest you to save your style in the style panel, vectorize your letter, make sure everything is overlapping (where there was a wild stroke) and then une the pathfinder ton make one big ol' shape !

Them re- apply your style and you're done !

Comment: When I say text I mean actual text. When I change fonts I have the same problem. When I go to Type/Create outline, then Object/Expand Appearances then Object/Path/Outline Stroke, then Object/Expand, it goes away, but I'm sure that's not the most efficient way. Also once converted to an outline, I'm unable to edit my text later if I want to change the font or something. Thank you, I'm open to suggestions/tips.

Answer (score 0):

It's a typical GPU acceleration issue. Turn it off/on. If GPU acceleration was on and you had this issue, check for GPU driver updates. In some cases BIOS update also solves the problem.